# jQuery show/hide on radio button change not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, bind, onchange

I have a form that shows/hide different info depending on which radio button you click. The code works fine in everything except IE7 (haven't tested IE6 but we are not supporting that anymore :) )

The script is triggered by the first set of radio buttons (Account type)

The fiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/HBr8f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure your markup is invalid, I wouldn’t use a `fieldset` as direct descendant to an `ul` element. Try validating your markup using the W3C validator.

Comment: I second this.  Your markup is not valid.  If you inspect the DOM using IE Developer Tools you can see that the elements are not being rendered where you want them to be.

Comment: Thanks you were spot on, it works fine now with a div or a span instead of a fieldset. Cheers